# Freezing token accounts issues

Tags: token

I was running into issues like:

`Error: This token mint cannot freeze accounts`

For `SetAuthority` and `FreezeAccount` for a token account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But then I realized it was due to the FreezeAuth being None, which makes it impossible to update freeze related aspects.

According to:
https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts